# Data points insertion error. Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series.?8

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, bar-chart

I want to generate a bar chart and dynamically display the details on it. I am trying to display bar chart with four values. But it is not working. My code is given below. Please help me

```
   public partial class chartDummy : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"ConnectionString");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Mains_Run_Hrs, DG_Run_Auto_Mode, Battery_Run_Hrs, Solar_Run_hrs from tbl_runtime_report", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataView source = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
            Chart1.DataSource = ds;
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Mains_Run_Hrs";
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "DG_Run_Auto_Mode";
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Battery_Run_Hrs";
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Solar_Run_hrs";
            Chart1.DataBind();

    }   
}
```

source:

```
  <div>
      <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1" Width="558px">
          <Series>
              <asp:Series Name="Main Run Hrs"></asp:Series>
              <asp:Series Name="DG Run Auto Mode"></asp:Series>
              <asp:Series Name="Battery Run Hrs"></asp:Series>
              <asp:Series Name="Solar Run Hrs"></asp:Series>
          </Series>
          <ChartAreas>
              <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
          </ChartAreas>
          <Legends>
              <asp:Legend Title="Solar Data"></asp:Legend>
          </Legends> 
      </asp:Chart>           
  </div>
```

Comment: What is `state.GetDummyChart()` returning? Shouldn't you be assigning the result to a DataTable, not a DataSet?

Comment: @DavidG : I have updated the code. But it generated another error.

Comment: Well now you have completely changed the question. Also, your code for populating the chart is mostly nonsense.

Comment: @DavidG: Actually I am  just a beginner in asp.net. So can you please help me. Do you have any solution.

Comment: I suggest you go and learn about the chart control :)

Comment: @DavidG : I don't have time to learn right now. Can you help me. Because I have to complete my mini project today.

Comment: If you don't have the time to learn, I don't have the time to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given below code is working perfectly. It showing the flow chard according to the db data. Thank you.

```
public partial class chartDummy : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"ConnectionString");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Mains_Run_Hrs, DG_Run_Auto_Mode, Battery_Run_Hrs, Solar_Run_hrs from tbl_runtime_report", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataView source = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
            Chart1.DataSource = ds;
            Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Mains_Run_Hrs";
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "DG_Run_Auto_Mode";
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Battery_Run_Hrs";
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Solar_Run_hrs";
            Chart1.DataBind();

    }   
}
```